Prism ViewModelLocator doesn't seem to work
I am currently working through the Doucmentation of Prism.Avalonia.
Somehow I generellay can not get for the life of me the VIewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel to work. It always throws me the error: "Cannot parse a compiled binding without an explicit X:DataType directive to give a starting data type for bindings."
I verified my View and ViewModel Naming Conventions.
I copied the code line for line from the official documentation.
Working through [this] (https://github.com/AvaloniaCommunity/Prism.Avalonia/tree/develop/samples/SampleMvvmApp)
sample project.
What are some common pitfalls when developing software with the Prism.Avalonia Framework?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
